# MPICC error when installing mpi4py despite correct and working MPICC installation

Tags: python, mpi, pip, mpi4py

I have successfully installed MPICH on Ubuntu 12.04 and can get the simple test C programs to compile and run as expected.

Now I am trying to use pip to install mpi4py, simply via `pip install mpi4py`. I first executed `sudo apt-get build-dep python-mpi4py` which worked fine.

I'm working with virtualenv, so this mpi4py installation is not with sudo (and should not be).

Here's the command and the error that I hit after a lengthy set of console output that looks like normal compile stuff (I can print *all* of the console output if needed, but I think most of it is standard compiler warnings that indicate no problems).

```
(local-dev)espears@espears-w:~$ pip install mpi4py
src/ext/mpi_swig.c: In function ‘SWIG_Python_AddErrorMsg’:

src/ext/mpi_swig.c:859:5: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]

cc1: some warnings being treated as errors

error: command '/usr/bin/mpicc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /home/espears/.virtualenvs/local-dev/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/home/espears/.virtualenvs/local-dev/build/mpi4py/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-5o6OwN-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/espears/.virtualenvs/local-dev/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /home/espears/.virtualenvs/local-dev/build/mpi4py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/espears/.virtualenvs/local-dev/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/espears/.virtualenvs/local-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/home/espears/.virtualenvs/local-dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 31: ordinal not in range(128)
```

But, `which mpicc` gives the expected result: `/usr/bin/mpicc` and as mentioned above, if I use this `mpicc` to compile simple .c test programs, they work fine.

I've seen some links describing a flag option `fPIC` for compiling MPI, but, I merely used apt-get to install MPI and specifically want to only rely on native Ubuntu packages for these tools, as opposed to maintaining separate installation instructions for manually building them.

How can I determine why `mpicc` is failing within the `mpi4py` installation process?

**Added**

The following from the console output seems to be the compilation command that causes the trouble.

```
building 'mpi4py._mpi_swig' extension

/usr/bin/mpicc -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/ext/mpi_swig.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/ext/mpi_swig.o
```

This gives the following error when I try from the command line myself:

```
(local-dev)espears@espears-w:~$ /usr/bin/mpicc -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/ext/mpi_swig.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/ext/mpi_swig.o
gcc: error: src/ext/mpi_swig.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: That error is a compilation error, not a compiler not found error.

Comment: Added more about the specific compile command that seems to be the problem. I can't find anything useful on why mpi_swig.c would be missing.

Comment: The build process probably runs in a different directory than the one where you execute the compile command. That's why the relative path is invalid and you are getting the no such file error. Another option would be that the `mpi_swig.c` file is being automatically generated by SWIG and then deleted.

Comment: Any workaround for these, or even diagnostic tips so I can verify if one or the other is happening. I'm not even sure what plain `src/` directory is being referenced here. All of the `mpicc` `mpiexec` and `mpirun` stuff seems fine when I examine it, and all is built for MPICH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to successfully work around this with no changes to anything in my system simply by pointing pip at the MPI4PY package url, rather than the package name:

```
pip install https://bitbucket.org/mpi4py/mpi4py/downloads/mpi4py-1.3.1.tar.gz
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Mr. F, you saved my day :)

Comment: @ComputerScientist Can you post a separate question with your specific error and add a link in a comment here? I just created a fresh conda environment both for Python 2.7.11 and for Python 3.6.2, and in both cases, the same `pip install` command from my answer works without a problem. It also works if specifying a newer version URL for mpi4py, such as for version 3.0.0. Since this method works, we would need to see your specific error messages or issues to know what is different about your situation preventing it from working for you.

Comment: Similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58355271/error-when-installing-mpi4py-on-ubuntu-instance

Answer (score 2):

A similar problem was encountered on Ubuntu 18.04 with openmpi-4.0.0.
Solved by installing older version of openmpi-2.1.6.

```
apt-get install openmpi=2.1.6
```