# Error when installing mpi4py on Ubuntu instance

Tags: python, ubuntu

I'm trying to install mpi4py on my Ubuntu 18.04 instance. I have python3.6.5 installed.

First I try `sudo apt-get build-dep python-mpi4py` and I get:

> Reading package lists... Done E: You must put some 'source' URIs in
>   your sources.list

I then try to install simply with `pip install mpi4py`. I get a long error message and I include some of the most important parts below:

```
checking for library 'lmpe' ...
  /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  The Open MPI wrapper compiler was unable to find the specified compiler
  x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc in your PATH.

  Note that this compiler was either specified at configure time or in
  one of several possible environment variables.
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  failure.
```

This failure occurs for most libraries. I include just one of the many, and

```
  warning: build_clib: command '/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/bin/mpicc' failed with exit status 1

  warning: build_clib: building optional library "vt-mpi" failed


  checking for library 'vt-hyb' ...
  /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/bin/mpicc -pthread -B /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/compiler_compat -Wl,--sysroot=/ -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -c _configtest.c -o _configtest.o
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------
  The Open MPI wrapper compiler was unable to find the specified compiler
  x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc in your PATH.

  Note that this compiler was either specified at configure time or in
  one of several possible environment variables.
```

Running `which mpcc` gives:

```
(tensorflow_p36) ubuntu@ip-172-31-35-200:~$ which mpicc
/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p36/bin/mpicc
```

How can I add the specified compiler x86_64-conda_cos6-linux-gnu-cc to my PATH in order to resolve this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply run:

`conda install -c anaconda mpi4py` as shown [here](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/mpi4py).

Also, a [helpful comment](https://bitbucket.org/mpi4py/mpi4py/issues/118/cannot-pip-install-mpi4py-with-conda) by Lidandro Dalcin:

> I guess you are missing the mpich-mpicc package, this one is a
>   metapackage that depends in the right compiler. Why are you installing
>   mpi4py with pip? Maybe all you need is to conda install mpi4py
>   (available in the conda-forge channel) ?

Answer (score 0):

Or if you don't want to use conda...

`sudo apt install mpi-default-dev`